# Useful versioning scheme for a git project?

Tags: git, versioning

I have a small github project, which I need to add an option to to output some version number on the commandline.

The problem is I have no idea how to "compute" the version number. Is this some random process? Should I just start at 1.0 (probably creating a tag or something), and put a number after `.` for fixes?

I know this question is a bit vague... I just had never to deal with this, and want to use some sane versioning scheme.

**EDIT**

Im also interested into how to update this version number automatically, maybe using something like a git hook.

Comment: using any CI tool? Teamcity for one, can pass and handle versioning schemes

Comment: @JamesWoolfenden I'm using git, but git commits don't seem very useful (being SHAs).

Comment: You may also find the following answer useful: > http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/141973/how-do-you-achieve-a-numeric-versioning-scheme-with-git

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/). What constitutes a major, minor and patch version increment depends on your project, but the site is a good starting point. You might also want to include the first few digits of the git commit ID in the version, so you can find it later.